# Почему в java генерики в функциях выглядят так <T>foo(arg) а не так foo<T>(arg)?

Tags: java

Почему в java генерики в функциях выглядят так "<T>foo(arg)", а не так "foo<T>(arg)" ?
Мне просто интересно сделано ли это по техническим причинам, или "чтобы было не как на плюсах". В большинстве(по моим наблюдениям) языков используется именно второй вариант и сделать так, чтобы большинству людей не пришлось перепривыкать было бы разумнее.

Comment: В большинстве случаев, другие языки можно не знать.

Answer (score 0):

потому что типы пишутся перед именем метода

Comment: Вопрос в том почему выбран именно такой синтаксис. А если точнее, было ли это сделано из-за стилистических соображений, или есть технические причины. Например, что в случае написания foo<T>() будет неоднозначность в синтаксисе или, что <T>foo() просто проще парсить при компиляции.

Comment: скорее всего из-за обратной совместимости

Comment: @VAVUS7 аналлы [JSR-14](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se6/html/classes.html#8.1.2)